# How to set from a flat view a google map to a whole globe view?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently developing a small android app with a Google Map API integrated and I want to change the zoom / (the display view) from flat to a global world view that can be rotate. I saw in google maps link this kind of zoom: 2.74z.

I mention that I tried to set the zoom to a very small value but it didn't work.

Here is my method:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    LatLng location = new LatLng(43.0026165,25.2378221);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Home"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newLatLng(location));
    map.setMinZoomPreference(1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that it will help:

For having a nice Globe View I used a library:
implementation 'com.mousebirdconsulting.maply:Android:2.5'

You can find a full tutorial here: 
[WhirlyGlobe Tutorial](https://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/)